# Require.js ignoring baseUrl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

OK this is driving me crazy so maybe someone can point me in the right direction...

I'm using the latest require.js combined with jquery as my module loader. I am using the `data-main` attribute to point to a config file with a `baseUrl`. When I try to load a module the `baseUrl` is ignored and require is attempting to load from the same location as `main.js`.

**/js/main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/vendor/'
});
```

**/path/to/page.html**

```
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/vendor/require-jquery.js"></script>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
    $(function() {
        console.log('hello world!');
    });
});
</script>
```

**Expected:**

Loads `http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/bootstrap.js` and logs `hello world!`

**Actual:**

Attempts to load`http://localhost:3000/js/bootstrap.js` -- Fails :'(

I've tried using relative paths instead of absolute paths for both `data-main` and `src` in the require script tag. Nothing I do seems to trigger the `baseUrl`. Am I totally missing something in the docs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the trouble is that require.js load script asynchronously (that's the point behind requirejs), so when you add the `require()` into a script tag right after you load require, this script execute before `js/main.js` get loaded.

The easy way would be to include all this in `main.js`, or create a new file to hold this piece and load it from js/main

**/js/main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/vendor/'
});

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
    $(function() {
        console.log('hello world!');
    });
});
```

**-- OR --**

**/js/main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/vendor/',
    deps: ['../boostrap']
});
```

**/js/boostrap.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
    $(function() {
        console.log('hello world!');
    });
});
```

*note `require()` became a `define()` in the bootstrap file*

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'm using layouts and partials in EJS so I actually went with a third option which was to define a global require object before adding any JS and I toss my options in there. The docs talk about it here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Answer (score 7):

Your config is being executed in async mode. When first `require` call is founded, your config is not yet applied. According to documentation:

> when `require.js` loads it will inject another script tag
>       (with async attribute) for `scripts/main.js`

So, just execute your config in sync mode:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/require-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
  $(function() {
    console.log('hello world!');
  });
});
</script>
```

More info: [Patterns for separating config from the main module](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module)