# Require JS is ignoring my config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having pretty simple directory structure for scripts:

```
/js/        <-- located in site root
    libs/
        jquery-1.10.1.min.js
        knockout-2.2.1.js
        knockout.mapping.js
    models/
        model-one.js
        model-two.js
        ...
    require.js
    config.js
```

Since the site engine uses clean URLs I'm using absolute paths in `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

RequireJS config:

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: "/js/libs",

    paths: {
        "jquery":       "jquery-1.10.1.min",
        "knockout":     "knockout-2.2.1",
        "komapping":    "knockout.mapping"
    }

});
```

Somewhere in HTML:

```
require(["jquery", "knockout", "komapping"], function($, ko, mapping){
    // ...
});
```

So the problem is that RequireJS completely ignores `baseUrl` and `paths` defined in config file. I get 404 error for every module required in the code below. I see in browser console that RequireJS tries to load these modules from `/js/` without any path translations:

```
404: http://localhost/js/jquery.js
404: http://localhost/js/knockout.js
404: http://localhost/js/komapping.js
```

However after the page is loaded and the errors are shown I type in console and...

```
> require.toUrl("jquery")
  "/js/libs/jquery-1.10.1.min"
```

Why so? How to solve this problem?

It's my first experience using RequireJS, so I'm feeling like I've skipped something very simple and obvious. Help, please.

**Update**

Just discovered this question: [Require.js ignoring baseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574255/require-js-ignoring-baseurl)

It's definitely my case. I see in my Network panel that `config.js` is not completely loaded before `require(...)` fires own dependency loading.

But I don't want to place my `require(...)` in config because it is very specific for the page that calls it. I've never noticed such problem with asynchronicity in any example seen before. How do authors of these examples keep them working?

Comment: did you try to remove first trailing slash 'js/libs/' ?

Comment: @paka Just tried. No changes.

Comment: does it works with absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, it works with absolute paths (excepting `ko-mapping` since it depends on `knockout`).

Comment: so, you have to figure out the right path from script (config) to libs... http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: Seems you don't understand me. If I use `require(["/full/path/jquery.js"], ...)` instead of `require(["jquery"], ...)` then all it works fine.

Comment: This is a simple solution solve you problem:

[Require.js ignoring baseUrl][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28278265/1882644

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was that config file defined in `data-main` attribute is loaded asynchronously just like other dependencies. So my `config.js` accidentally was never completely loaded and executed before `require` call.

The solution is described in official RequireJS API: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

> ... Also, you can define the config object as the global variable require before require.js is loaded, and have the values applied automatically.

So I've just changed my `config.js` to define global `require` hash with proper configuration:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/js/libs",
    paths: {
        "jquery":       "jquery-1.10.1.min",
        "knockout":     "knockout-2.2.1",
        "komapping":    "knockout.mapping"
    }
};
```

and included it just BEFORE `require.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

This approach allows to control script execution order, so `config.js` will always be loaded before next `require` calls.

All works perfectly now.

Comment: It will say require is not defined

Comment: Thanks, this works but it caused a small issue in another script that read: require is not a function. (Think it has something to do with variable scope) To avoid this you can use requirejs = {...} instead of require = {...}. Seems to do the same thing but without the issue. In addition you might want to create a script tag in the template to define a variable eg. var webroot = 'http://path/to/webroot' before the config include and set "baseUrl: webroot," in the config.js to prevent routing problems caused by seo urls.

Comment: This solution is ugly, you are assigning a global variable that will be overridden after library's declaration. Just put your config in a separated script tag, right after require.js. More info: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the issue.

My config was being loaded asynchronously, and therefore the config paths weren't set before my require statement was being called.

As per the RequireJS docs [Link here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), I added a script call to my config before the require.js call. And removed the data-main attribute.

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery':      'vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min',
        'picker':      'vendor/pickadate/picker.min',
        'pickadate':   'vendor/pickadate/picker.date.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'picker':    ['jquery'],
        'pickadate': {
            deps:    ['jquery', 'picker'],
            exports: 'DatePicker'
        }
    }
}
```

All is now working

Comment: Very grateful for this - I was getting all sorts of issues with scripts not loading properly and could never find the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Really helped me out.