# RequireJS path 'alias' problems

Tags: requirejs

Getting mighty tired fighting to get requireJS to work in a predictable manner. Its debugging support is underwhelming.

My config.js file as follows:

```
require.config({

baseUrl: "Scripts",

paths: {
    "jquery": "jquery-2.1.1.min",
    "bootstrap": "bootstrap.min",
    "knockout": "knockout-3.1.0"
},
shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "$.fn.popover"
    }
},
enforceDefine: true
});
require(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function ($, bootstrap) {
    console.log("(A) loaded jq + bs");
    if ($)
        console.log("$ is present");
    if (bootstrap)
        console.log("bootstrap is present");
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Config.js.map
```

JavaScript in the /Scripts folder, which is where Config.js resides. 'jquery' is supposed to alias to a specific version, but when the browser loads it tries to load `/Scripts/jquery.js`

The aliased file `/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js` exists.

The same happens with bootstrap - it loads `boostrap.js` instead of `bootstrap.min.js`

I hate the way requireJS has this arcane way of mixing different behaviours into the same path setting, which changes based on string contents.

Comment: I think config is not getting loaded before the alias things. can you provide some fiddle link for your code?

Comment: It's a pretty basic asp.net web app for testing requireJS. I looked at the network queries in the dev tools on IE and chrome, require is loaded, then config.js.. then it tries to load /Scripts/jquery.js

Comment: Which version of require are you using? Are you using two versions or something like that?

Comment: This link may help you. Check this once... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341015/require-js-is-ignoring-my-config

Comment: Thanks @Priya - it was the config.js being loaded asynchronously. I removed it from data-main into a second script tag and it worked. Please can you post this answer so I can give you the kudos!!

Comment: I've fixed it for now by removing the data-main tag, and specifying config.js as a script tag. But that begs the question, why is the other method commonly used in examples if it causes this issue? More searching required..

Comment: I completely agree with that.. But In requirejs docs they mentioned like this is asynchronous(http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) and they provided an example. so examples should be provided atleast with some note that it is asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link may help you.. the configuration file is being loaded asynchronously and has not been executed when you first call require()

Check this one
[Require JS is ignoring my config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341015/require-js-is-ignoring-my-config)