# jQuery is not working with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I know that my question is so similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341015/require-js-is-ignoring-my-config), but I have the same problem and none of the solutions work for me.

My directory structure is the following:

```
static
    lib
        require.js
        jquery-1.11.3.js
        progressbar.js   
    client
        client.messages.js
        client.js
    main.js
    config.js
```

My HTML file is like this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/lib/require.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl: "/static/script",
        paths: {
        /* Load common libraries from CDN and fallback to local versions. */
        "jquery":      "lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
        "progressbar": "lib/progressbar.min.js",
        "messages":    "client/client.messages.js"
        }
    };
</script>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/main.js') }}"></script>
```

I have also tried to make the configuration in the config.js file which was like:

```
var require = {
        baseUrl: "/static/script",
    paths: {
        /* Load common libraries from CDN and fallback to local versions. */
        "jquery":      "lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
        "progressbar": "lib/progressbar.min.js",
        "messages":    "client/client.messages.js"
    }
};
```

and then the HTML file was like:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/config.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/lib/require.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/main.js') }}"></script>
```

Further down in my HTML file there is this line:

```
<body onload="bodyLoaded()">
```

and this `bodyLoaded()` function is in my main.js:

```
var bodyLoaded = function () {
    //load scripts first
    var scripts = ['static/scripts/client/client.messages.js', 'static/scripts/client/client.js'];
    $.getScript(scripts[0], function () {
        $.getScript(scripts[1], function () {
            pluginCheck();
        });
    });
};
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

for this line in `bodyload()`:

```
$.getScript(scripts[0], function () {
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to change `$` for `jQuery`?

Comment: Sorry, can you make your point a bit more clear? What exactly can I change?

Comment: Try changing the code `$.getScript(...` to `jQuery.getScript(...`

Comment: No, there is (almost) the same error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you're loading RequireJS, you've configured it, but you are not **using it**.

One way to get what you want would be:

```
var bodyLoaded = function () {
    //load scripts first
    var scripts = ['static/scripts/client/client.messages.js', 'static/scripts/client/client.js'];
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $.getScript(scripts[0], function () {
            $.getScript(scripts[1], function () {
                pluginCheck();
            });
        });
     });
};
```

I've added `require(['jquery'], ...` so that jQuery actually gets loaded.

This being said, it is very likely that this is not the solution you want to end with. For one thing, it seems to me that `client.messages.js` and `client.js` are candidates for being loaded with RequireJS so, really, RequireJS should be configured to find them (I see `client.message.js` in the config but not `client.js`). You'll most likely have to use `shim` to define the dependencies among them.

I suggest that you thoroughly read [RequireJS' documentation](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem. I have not used `client.js` till now and that's why I have not loaded.