# Requirejs uses wrong path for asset in library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In a website I'm creating [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is used as module loader. There is a "3d photo viewer" on this website and I'm using the [Photo Sphere Viewer lib](http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/) for these. One of the dependencies for this library is [D.js](http://malko.github.io/D.js/). This is required in the library code as such:

```
... define(["three","D.js","uevent","doT"],b) ...
```

In my RequireJS configuration I defined a `baseUrl` and `path`s for the libs required by Photo Sphere Viewer libraries:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/scripts',
  paths: {
    'vendor':       'lib/vendor',
    'three':        'lib/vendor/three',
    'uevent':       'lib/vendor/uEvent',
    'doT':          'lib/vendor/dOT',
    'D.js':         'lib/vendor/D'
  }
});
```

`photo-sphere-viewer` is required by the website after a user requests to get a 3d photo. Code works a little like this:

```
requirejs(['main', 'deps', 'for', 'app'], function(a, b, c, d){
  var showSphere = function(){
    // loading logic and such
    require('vendor/photos-sphere-viewer', function(PSV){
      // do your 3d photo thing
    });
  };
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', showSphere);
});
```

`D.js` is located at `/scripts/lib/vendor/D.js`. However when I test this, I get a 404 for `/D.js`. As if it is completely ignoring the `baseUrl` and `path`, but these aren't ignored for the other libraries, these get loaded normally.

I've added `console.log(require.urlTo('D.js'))` to the top of the Photo Sphere Viewer js file and somehow this logs the correct path: `"/scripts/lib/vendor/D.js"`. However, one line further when `D.js` is actually required it seems to have 'changed its mind'. I've working on this for some time without result and I'm kinda considering just putting `D.js` in the website root, but of course that's not my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the .js is throwing things off.
Change the config

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/scripts',
  paths: {
    'vendor':       'lib/vendor',
    'three':        'lib/vendor/three',
    'uevent':       'lib/vendor/uEvent',
    'doT':          'lib/vendor/dOT',
    'D_js':         'lib/vendor/D'
  }
});
```

And call the define this way.

```
define(["three","D_js","uevent","doT"],b) ...
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had to change the name in my config, the `photo-sphere-viewer` js file, and change the definition in `D.js` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is because of asynchronous loading of requireJs dependencies.
Since requireJs loads the dependencies asynchronously, the D.js file might not have been loaded yet when you are trying to use it.

If thats the problem, solution is to load the dependencies in a separate file before your require.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

See
[Require JS is ignoring my config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341015/require-js-is-ignoring-my-config)

 and http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: I highly doubt this is the issue, since the error isn't that `D` is `undefined` (or similar), but that the actual .js file couldn't be downloaded. Also code within `require('vendor/photos-sphere-viewer', function(PSV){ /* your 3d photo thing */ });` isn't triggered, so no code using the `D.js` lib is running. As I proposed in the question, moving the file to `/D.js` fixed it, but this is really not what I'd want to do.